# fields_for doesn't save object sin rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im interested why does my nested form in RoR doesnt save child objects :(

For now, it just save the Parent (Printer) value and makes the child(Color) disappear on second render (error)! What Am I doing wrong?

Parent model

```
class Printer < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
validates :user_id, presence: true
validates :model, presence: true

has_many :colors, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :colors
end
```

Child model

```
class Color < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :printer
    validates :color, presence: true

end
```

View (new.html.erb)

```
      <%= form_for @printer do |p|%>

      <%= p.text_field :model %>
      <%= p.fields_for :colors do |color|%>
          <%= color.text_field :color%>
      <% end %>

      <%= p.submit "Add"%>
  <% end %>
```

And controller

```
def create
@printer = current_user.printers.build(printer_params)
if @printer.save
  redirect_to @current_user
else
  render 'new'
end
end

def new
 @printer = Printer.new
 @printer.colors.build
end

private
def printer_params
  params.require(:printer).permit(:model)
end
```

**Edit:**
This one helps

```
private
def printer_params
  params.require(:printer).permit(:model, colors_attributes: [:color])
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using nested forms, you need to specify which nested attributes should be whitelisted:

```
def printer_params
  params.require(:printer).permit(:model, colors_attributes: [:color])
end
```

You can read more about it at [Rails Guides - Form Helpers - the controller section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#the-controller) and at [RoR API documentation - Strong Parameters](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html)

Comment: Thank you! I knew that something might be wrong with attributes, but didn't know how to list them. This is exactly what I was looking for.